# How can I make the reaction collector choose the first 2 reactions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I try to make reaction collector that pause/play the music after user react to the reaction, But my collector stops when user react 1 time (the user can't react twice, only once), how can i fix it?
this is my code:

```
 queue.textChannel.send(thing).then((question) => {
          question.react('⏸');
          question.react('▶️');
          question.react('⬅️');
          question.react('⏹️');


          const filter = (reaction, user) => {
             return ['⏹️', '⬅️','⏸','▶️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
          };

          const collector = question.createReactionCollector(filter, {
             max: 1,
             time: 0
          }); 


          collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
             if (reason === 'time') {
                msg.reply('Times Up');
             } else {

                const userReaction = collected.array()[0];
 
                const emoji = userReaction._emoji.name;
```

Comment: Why do you use the [`max: 1`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions) option if you want to collect more than one message?

Comment: I used max: 2, and It is not working even for one reaction.

Comment: Well, if you only listen for the [`end`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-end) event, it won't get triggered if you collect one reaction. `end` is only triggered when the collector is finished collecting (i.e. reached `max` or `time`). You should use the [`collect`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect) event instead.

Comment: One of you should post that as an accepted answer so it can help people having similar issues in the future @ZsoltMeszaros

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the collector from 'end' to 'collect'
and deleted the max: option.

```
            queue.textChannel.send(thing).then((question) => {
          question.react('⏸');
          question.react('▶️');
          question.react('⬅️');
          question.react('⏹️');


          const filter = (reaction, user) => {
             return ['⏹️', '⬅️','⏸','▶️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
          };

      const collector = question.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 400000 });



      collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {

 
                const emoji = reaction.emoji.name;
```

@ZsoltMeszaros Helped me with the right answer.